# general solution of the FODE $\frac{1}{\sin(x)} \frac{dy}{dx} = y\sec(x) -2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

What's the general solution of the first order differential equation ?

$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\sin(x)} \frac{dy}{dx} = y\sec(x)-2,  \quad 0<x< \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align*}
$$

my solution is as follows but i think it's wrong

$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = y\tan(x) -2\sin(x) \\
\frac{dy}{dx} - y\tan(x) = -2\sin(x) \\
e^{-\int \tan(x)dx} = \cos(x)\\
y\,cos(x) = \int(-2\cos(x)\sin(x))dx\\
y =\cos(x) + \frac{C}{\cos(x)}
$$

Comment: It seems correct to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems correct to me...

$$y'-y\tan(x)=-2\sin(x)$$
$$y'-y\frac {\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=-2\sin(x)$$
$$\frac {y'\cos(x)-y\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=-2\sin(x)$$
$$({y}{\cos(x)})'=-\sin(2x)$$
Integrating ..
$${y(x)}{\cos(x)}=-\int \sin(2x) dx$$
$$y(x)=\frac 1 {\cos(x)}(\frac {\cos(2x)}2+K)$$

The same answer as yours.....with $\cos(2x)=2cos^2(x)-1$

$$\boxed {y(x)=\frac C {\cos(x)}+\cos(x)}$$

Comment: The easier way to arrive at OP's answer is to note that $$ -\int 2\sin x\cos x \ dx = \int \cos x \ d(\cos x) = \frac{\cos^2 x}{2} + C$$

Comment: Surely @Dylan I really took my time solving it